# Map of Foo[T] to Bar[T]

Tags: scala, existential-type, type-level-computation

Can this be done?

```
case class Foo[T](value: T)
case class Bar[T](value: T)

val map = mutable.Map.empty[Foo[_], Bar[_]]

map(Foo(1)) = Bar(1) // correct
map(Foo(1)) = Bar(1.1) // should cause a compiler error
```

It should allow any type `T`, as long as both `Foo#T` and `Bar#T` are the same.

Comment: A `Map` alone won't allow you to enforce that constraint, because `Map` takes two type parameters that are completely independent. You could define a wrapper class (around a `Map`) that would take a single type parameter (for both the keys and values of the underlying `Map`).

Comment: @Jubobs It looks like I will have to do that. I was just hoping for a nicer way to do this, as I will be making a subclass of something purely for the purpose of type constraints.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this, to force `Foo`'s and `Bar`'s `T` type parameters to be the same:

```
object Maps extends App {

  import scala.collection.mutable

  class C[T] {
    case class Foo(value: T)
    case class Bar(value: T)
  }

  val c = new C[Int]    
  import c._ // now Foo and Bar refer to c's types c.Foo and c.Bar

  val map = mutable.Map.empty[Foo, Bar]

  map(Foo(1)) = Bar(1) // correct
  map(Foo(1)) = Bar(1.1) // should cause a compiler error, and it does

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The problem with that is that I am using a framework that provides `Foo[_]`, which already is path-dependent on another context. Wrapping it in another class would really complicate things.